# Why doesn't the selector `sel` exist when I run `scrapy shell`?

Tags: python, scrapy

I ran `scrapy shell myurl` from the top-level directory of my project.  Below is the log output:

```
$ scrapy shell "http://www.aufeminin.com/forum/show0_3/grossesse.html"
2013-11-07 12:02:08+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.14.4 started (bot: auf)
2013-11-07 12:02:08+0100 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled extensions: TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, MemoryUsage, SpiderState
2013-11-07 12:02:09+0100 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2013-11-07 12:02:09+0100 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2013-11-07 12:02:09+0100 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled item pipelines: 
2013-11-07 12:02:09+0100 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 0.0.0.0:6023
2013-11-07 12:02:09+0100 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 0.0.0.0:6080
2013-11-07 12:02:09+0100 [AufemininKeywordClassifierSpider] INFO: Spider opened
2013-11-07 12:02:09+0100 [AufemininKeywordClassifierSpider] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.aufeminin.com/forum/show0_3/grossesse.html> (referer: None)
[s] Available Scrapy objects:
[s]   hxs        <HtmlXPathSelector xpath=None data=u'<html>\r\n<head>\r\n<title>Forum Grossesse -'>
[s]   item       {}
[s]   request    <GET http://www.aufeminin.com/forum/show0_3/grossesse.html>
[s]   response   <200 http://www.aufeminin.com/forum/show0_3/grossesse.html>
[s]   settings   <CrawlerSettings module=<module 'auf.settings' from '/home/louist/Desktop/auf/auf/settings.pyc'>>
[s]   spider     <AufKeywordSpider 'AufemininKeywordClassifierSpider' at 0x3d41ed0>
[s] Useful shortcuts:
[s]   shelp()           Shell help (print this help)
[s]   fetch(req_or_url) Fetch request (or URL) and update local objects
[s]   view(response)    View response in a browser
```

The tutorial suggests that I should have a variable called `sel` which contains a selector.  Why isn't this the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hxs` contains selector in your case.

Answer (score 1):

I think that is because you are reading the documentation of the latest version (`0.19`) and your installed version is lower. The usage is very similar.

Comment: that would explain it.  Thank you! (I feel very silly now...)